# problem computing chunk size of dask array after dask_image.imread

Tags: python, image, dask, tiff

I am trying to load a large array of images into a dask array using dask_image.imread.imread()

```
from dask_image.imread import imread as dask_read
from pathlib import Path
file_path = Path('/path/to/folder/')
region_name = 'R0000'
ch_name = 'C01'
channel_array = dask_read(file_path /  f'*{region_name}*{ch_name}*.tif')
channel_array
```

[image: output of cell 1]

here we have an array with 12 time points. At each time point we have volume 2048x2048 pixels square and 192 pixels deep. After assembling the array I would like to create a maximum projection of the first frame

```
import dask.array as da
m = da.max(channel_array[0], axis=0)
m
```

[image: output of cell 2]

So far so good. Next, I would like to save the projection as a .tif file:

```
from tifffile import imwrite
imwrite('/path/to/save/Max.tif', m)
```

This results in `ValueError: Array chunk size or shape is unknown. Possible solution with x.compute_chunk_sizes()`

After playing some more, I found that saving the image wasn't necessarily the problem, but manipulating the array in any way would produce the same error. For example, `arr = np.asarray(m)` or `m.compute_chunk_sizes()` both produce the same error.

This error can *NOT* be reproduced by creating a dask array of random values from scratch and walking through the same steps, thus, it seems to be something specific to the imread functionality. The images themselves seem fine, I can open, view, and save those directly with no issue.

I have seen some chatter about the dask imread functions on github previously, but haven't been able to follow the larger conversation. Is there a specific version that should be used? My environment has:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
dask                      2022.9.0           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dask-core                 2022.9.0           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dask-image                2021.12.0          pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
```

Answer (score 1):

After scrolling through the [dask-image issues](https://github.com/dask/dask-image/issues) on GitHub I found that this issue had [been reported previously](https://github.com/dask/dask-image/issues/220). Creating a new environment with the following packages solved this problem:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
dask                      2021.4.1           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dask-core                 2021.4.1           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dask-image                0.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
```